# ITpp ld cannot find -lfftw3 -llapack and -lblas

Tags: fortran, linker-errors

I install all the external directories required for ITPP compilation(cmake, Itpp-external, Itpp-4.3.0), but still currently facing an error as following:

```
administrator@ubuntu:~/Desktop/EEP_CC4B9_SBSD3B4_SP_DSTS_2$ make
`itpp-config --cflags`
g++  itpp_ctrl.o rsc_code.o Rayleigh.o irreg_conv_code.o punctured_nsc_code.o dsts.o conv_code.o puncturer.o sphere_packing.o rayleigh_channel.o fileser.o punctured_rsc_code.o softbit.o nsc_code.o robprob.o softsource.o repeater.o ITpp.o -o EEP_CC4B9_SBSD3B4_SP_DSTS.exe -l fftw3 -l lapack -l blas -litpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'EEP_CC4B9_SBSD3B4_SP_DSTS.exe' failed
make: *** [EEP_CC4B9_SBSD3B4_SP_DSTS.exe] Error 1
```

Install the external directories with Fortran compiler. Your response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean packages / libraries  (directories is a bit strange in this context)? looks like you are missing some external libraries / packages mentioned in the requirements like blas , lapack, fftw or, depending on your compiler, a combined package with these libraries / packages like MKL (for e.g. Intel)

Comment: Please see other questions and answers about the `ld: cannot find...` error. There are many. You should install the libraries and sometimes supply their location using the `-L` flag.

Comment: Thank you sir, It was resolved. Actually ''make install'' was run but could not access the usr/bin and usr/local directories to create files at that time . Later on I changed the permission of the folder and execute the "make install" command which makes it workable.